# Send push message more than once in a row

Tags: php, android, blackberry, push

I have successfully initiate push message using PHP script to Android ported apps. My question is like the subject, is it possible to send push message more than once in a row using blackberry push service? Because i have tried that and the device only received the first push message.

I am using php script in this thread

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Unable-to-send-push-message-on-se...

and i tried calling the function twice

```
$bbpush->send_notification($registatoin_ids, array("status" => 100, "total" => 2, "data" => '[
            {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
    ]'));
$bbpush->send_notification($registatoin_ids, array("status" => 100, "total" => 2, "data" => '[
            {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
    ]'));
```

Glad if anyone could answer

Comment: All you have to do is iterating over the messages/devices, it works seamless in a php page i made a year ago.

Comment: Do you have any link alexdd5 ? Is what i'm doing wrong? because i've done the same with android gcm and it's working

Comment: I found out using production credentials or evaluation don't have any effect